# Not getting token in phonegap push plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app with push plugin. I am not getting the token ID. 
When i logged, i got the following message

Please help

```
ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-01-09 15:14:21.315 PushNotification[2296:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] 
FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "PushPlugin463402949",
  "PushPlugin",
  "register",
  [
    {
      "alert" : "true",
      "ecb" : "onNotificationAPN",
      "sound" : "true",
      "badge" : "true"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your AppDelegate.m and paste this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

into

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

}
```

Then past this code before @end

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```